# CV with zero mean?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, reporting, coefficient-of-variation

Many of the papers I've been reading on glucose/insulin dynamics say:
"measurement error was assumed to be independent, gaussian with zero mean and known standard deviation, (CV = 2%)."

My question is, how do they have CV = 2% when mean is zero? I think CV = standard deviation/mean, so isn't this a divide by zero issue?

Comment: I think it's the **error** that's assumed to be mean zero.  The mean of the true underlying value is $\mu>0$.

Comment: OK great, I was thinking something similar but that still means I'm stuck with what the given CV value is telling me. When I have actual data to play with, do I calculate standard deviation for those measurements and mean to get this 2%? or is this 2% still related to the measurement error?

Comment: Sloppiness in statement is not the only issue here. A constant CV is strictly inconsistent with a single Gaussian. At best, the authors are reporting two approximations that are both roughly true, conditionally Gaussian errors and SD proportional to mean. It's unfortunately not out of the question that some ritual form of words is being copied from paper to paper without understanding.